# getView is null even after onViewCreated was called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `main activity` and three fragments `frag1`,`frag2`,`frag3`. and I am trying to pass value from `frag3` to `frag2`. To do that, I created an interface
and that interface is implemented by the `main activity` as shown below in the code. the problem I am facing now is, despite `frag2` is created and its
`view is created` as well, when the value arrives from `frag3` to `frag2` `*getView() method returns null*`

the below logcat output is to show that the view of `frag2` was created

> why getview of frag2 is null?

**mainactivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IValuePasser {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mTB = null;
    private TabLayout mTL = null;
    private ViewPager mVP = null;
    private VPagerAdapter mVPAdapter = null;

    private Frag_2 mFrag2 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.w(TAG, "onCreate()");

        mFrag2 = new Frag_2();
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void onValueChanged(int value) {
        this.mFrag2.fromFrag3(value);
    }
}
```

**frag3**:

```
public class Frag_3 extends Fragment {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private View mRootView = null;
    private TextView mtvText = null;
    private ATIncr mATIncr = null;

    IValuePasser mValPasser = null;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.w(TAG, "onAttach()");

        Log.v(TAG, "getView(): " + getView());
        this.mValPasser = (IValuePasser) context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.w(TAG, "onCreate()");

        this.mATIncr = new ATIncr();
        Log.v(TAG, "getView(): " + getView());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCreateView()");

        this.mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_3, container, false);
        this.mtvText = (TextView) this.mRootView.findViewById(R.id.frag3_tv);

        Log.v(TAG, "getView(): " + getView());
        return mRootView;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.w(TAG, "onResume()");

        this.mATIncr.execute();

        Log.v(TAG, "getView(): " + getView());
    }

    private class ATIncr extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.w(TAG, "onPreExecute()");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.w(TAG, "doInBackground()");

            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
                publishProgress(i);
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Log.w(TAG, "onPostExecute()");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Log.w(TAG, "onProgressUpdate()");

            mtvText.setText("" + values[0]);
            mValPasser.onValueChanged(values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

**frag2**:

```
public class Frag_2 extends Fragment {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private View mRootView = null;
    private TextView mtvText = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCreateView()");

        this.mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_2, container, false);
        this.mtvText = (TextView) this.mRootView.findViewById(R.id.frag2_tv);

        Log.v(TAG, "getView(): " + getView());
        return mRootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.w(TAG, "onViewCreated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.w(TAG, "onActivityCreated()");
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public void fromFrag3(int value) {
        if (getView() != null) {
            this.mtvText.setText("" + value);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "getViwe(): " + getView());
        }
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
02-09 10:08:25.050 25092-25092/? W/Frag_1: onAttach()
02-09 10:08:25.050 25092-25092/? W/Frag_1: onCreate()
02-09 10:08:25.050 25092-25092/? W/Frag_1: onCreateView()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_1: onViewCreated()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_1: onActivityCreated()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_1: onStart()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_1: onResume()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_2: onAttach()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_2: onCreate()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_2: onCreateView()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? V/Frag_2: getView(): null
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_2: onViewCreated()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_2: onActivityCreated()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onAttach()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? V/Frag_3: getView(): null
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onCreate()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? V/Frag_3: getView(): null
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onCreateView()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? V/Frag_3: getView(): null
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onViewCreated()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? V/Frag_3: getView(): android.widget.RelativeLayout{18d55403 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onActivityCreated()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? V/Frag_3: getView(): android.widget.RelativeLayout{18d55403 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_2: onStart()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_2: onResume()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onStart()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? V/Frag_3: getView(): android.widget.RelativeLayout{18d55403 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onResume()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onPreExecute()
02-09 10:08:25.060 25092-25092/? V/Frag_3: getView(): android.widget.RelativeLayout{18d55403 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
02-09 10:08:25.070 25092-25111/? W/Frag_3: doInBackground()
```

**logcat when frag3 passes to frag2**:

```
02-09 10:08:29.080 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onProgressUpdate()
02-09 10:08:29.080 25092-25092/? D/Frag_2: getViwe(): null
02-09 10:08:30.080 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onProgressUpdate()
 02-09 10:08:30.080 25092-25092/? D/Frag_2: getViwe(): null
02-09 10:08:30.140 308-308/? E/SMD: DCD ON
02-09 10:08:31.090 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onProgressUpdate()
02-09 10:08:31.090 25092-25092/? D/Frag_2: getViwe(): null
02-09 10:08:32.090 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onProgressUpdate()
02-09 10:08:32.090 25092-25092/? D/Frag_2: getViwe(): null
02-09 10:08:32.920 795-4291/? D/SSRM:n: SIOP:: AP = 340, PST = 345, CUR =   450
02-09 10:08:33.080 25092-25092/? W/Frag_3: onProgressUpdate()
02-09 10:08:33.080 25092-25092/? D/Frag_2: getViwe(): null
```

Comment: `getView()` is returning `null` because view is not created in `onCreateView()`, Use `mRootView` instead.

Comment: the question is about why getView returns null even after onViewCreated not about using or not mRootView

Comment: @user2121  ... please log onDestroyView/onStop/onPause too ... are all fragments visible at the same time ?

Comment: @Selvin i did, and as shown in the logs in the question..ondestroy,stop,pause never called

Comment: I bet that it is not the same instance of Frag_2 ...

Answer (score 0):

You set it null in main `private Frag_2 mFrag2 = null;` and call it from `this.mFrag2.fromFrag3(value);`. Also mFrag2 isn't initialized in `onCreate()` Now its null and you try to give value with `fromFrag3(value)`. Lets look at `fromFrag3`. It checks if its view is null. You send null view and it passes setText in this if statement:

```
if (getView() != null) {
    this.mtvText.setText("" + value);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "getViwe(): " + getView());
}
```

You must remove null value from `mFrag2`.

Comment: i edited my question, actuall mFrag2 was initialised in onCreate of the main activity but i have not posted

Comment: Did you try to remove "= null"? I mean you set it null you don't change it because of ( getView() != null ) statement. It never enters "this.mtvText.setText("" + value);"